# How to add my bnd jars dependencies to my eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, dependency-management, bnd, bndtools

I have some core plugins created in my workspace that are built with BND tools in eclipse. Now I have to reference those core plugins in my eclipse RCP application which is developed with PDE tool in eclipse. But there is no visibility to the BND generated plugins inside the RCP application. May be I can manually copy those plugins to a folder and add the folder to the target. But I want to get rid of such manual task.

Is there any easy way to add the BND generated plugins as dependencies to my RCP application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try with recent version of eclipse and bndtools 
But you can try my experiment done 4 year ago 
https://github.com/filippor/bndPdeTarget